# Is it possible that nginx reuse connections to backend http-flv streaming server to serve mutiple clients

Tags: nginx, streaming, live-streaming, http-live-streaming, flv

I have a backend encoding server serving live streams by http-flv as well as rtmp.
I am trying to utilize http-flv stream instead of rtmp stream. What I do is to serve clients the http-flv stream through a nginx server. Here is the snippet of my nginx conf file.

```
location /live/news {
    proxy_pass http://encodingserver:8088/flv0;
}
```

It is working.

However, for performance consideration, I am thinking about reusing the connection between nginx and encoding server.

Is it possible for nginx "copy" stream directly instead of opening a new connection to backend encoding server when a new client starts to play since it is a live streaming connection and sessionless?

I want to make the workload of encoding server as small as possible.